# contraints on equation of a cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry

(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2

any way to adjust this formula to add constraints to the z-axis? recently introduced to the idea this goes forever in z-axis and I want to see if theres way's to adjust formula so I can get points on either side of the z-axis

Comment: What range of z values do you want?

Comment: any, i just want to see if theres a way to add a variable to give gonstraints to the z axis....example: (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2  + (z-c)^2  ?     Since I've recently just been introduced to vector calc I can't do it on my own

Comment: The equation $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2 = r^2$ gives you a sphere with radius $r$ and center $(a,b,c)$. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a single formula, this describes a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$, centred on $(a,b,c)$:

$$\max\left(\frac{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}{r^2},\frac{2|z-c|}{h}\right) = 1$$

But I don't think that it's very much use for anything.

Comment: thanks much, what does the max stand for?

Comment: max(s,t) is the maximum of s and t.

Comment: Note that this formula includes disk-shaped "caps" on the top and bottom. Is this what the OP wants?